# ReferenceError: "document" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites, referenceerror

Im new to JavaScript and even more new to Google Apps Script. Im trying a simple function that shows the current date (only day, month e and full year), but the Google Script show the error  ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.

My goal is to use this function in a Google Site. Here is the code:

```
function Data()
{
var d=new Date();
var dia=d.getDate();
var mes=d.getMonth();
var ano=d.getFullYear();
var DataCompleta=dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano
document.write(DataCompleta);
}
```

Comment: In a browser it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/t4PbY/

Comment: Yes, for me too, but not in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the former answer you can't execute a function directly in the Browser, you'll have to choose a so called '[container](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_methods)' to run your function from it. I would recommand you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/your_first_script) and maybe try a few [simple tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) to see how GAS can be executed.

---

**EDIT :** following your comments, feel free to have a look at [this script](https://script.google.com/d/1I23ey7VM-N2_UbxSEIngF1RuGlCKknb7-gjH9kcKix93npqHawMI1VrO/edit) built with UiApp, the result is viewable [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzqfGfsJ9ugtAvIBvJDZSg1LfAcX1jGNnW8erYUfKjOddJHlJs/exec) and shows what you wanted to : **"Hello, today is 25/10/2012"**

Comment: I read the documentation, but it seems that i´m not understanding :)
My code stills not working, giving the ReferenceError: **"document" is not defined**.

GAS does not uses this Object?

I changed my to this:

`function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Data.html')
}

function Data()
{
var d=new Date();
var dia=d.getDate();
var mes=d.getMonth();
var ano=d.getFullYear();
var DataCompleta=dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
document.write(DataCompleta);
}`

in another file named Data.html i did this:
`<html>
<script>
  google.script.run.Data();
</script>
</html>`

Comment: [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) should help you, there is no need for "document" object, don't forget that script are executed on the cloud, not in your Browser. The HTML service you are trying allows you to mix both client and server code execution but is not (to my opinion) the easiest to understand... (because of these two aspects) so why not begin with a simple script file written in the script editor like [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the scriptlet tags and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Code running as a Google Apps Script does not run in the browser, so you cannot use web browser APIs with it. If you want to output content to a Google Site, then you need to use the [API for Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_sites).

Presumably you would want something like [`createWebPage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site#createWebPage) and then use [the methods on the resulting object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_page) to add the content to it.

Comment: no, i dont want to create a page, but only show the current date. you know, when you open a webpage and in the top of the content says "Hello, today is 11/25/2012!". Something like that...

Comment: For that, you need [a `<script>` element in the page](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2500646). Apps Script isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: thanks @Quentin. Im trying to insert this code in a Google Site and in another help topic, they say that do not accept Javascript. Isn't confuse?
http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90540

Comment: @user1851272 — Yes, Google appears to have contradictory documentation. I'd use a normal web hosting service instead.

Comment: Google Sites does not allow JavaScript in the core Sites page. You can add it via Apps Script (specifically, HtmlService) or the Sites-specific "HTML Box".